# Align Facebook Like Button with Counts box

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I need to align the Facebook likes count box to the bottom of my Like Button for my website. Can any one help me with this?

I need to position or style the fb button as shown:

[image: Facebook like button]

Comment: please add a screenshot of what you are doing or have done?

Comment: And (If possible) the relevant markup / CSS would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you may scale the size to suit your needs, you may not modify the Like Button in any other way (such as by changing the design).

Please see the Facebook Like Button Usage section at [the Facebook Brand Permissions Center](https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php).

Comment: The "count box" is part of the Like Button design. In addition, it is loaded by an iFrame hosted at FB servers. Thanks

Comment: So the two visually separate objects are actually one and the same object.  Now your comment about modifying the like button makes sense.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the count to appear above the Like button by setting layout_style = "box_count" - but there is no option to have the count display BELOW the like button.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/